Nuxt.js Content and Nuxt I18n: How to create a localized content
I am working on a Nuxt.js project that uses @nuxt/content and @nuxtjs/i18n modules to create a localized blog.
If I use content/blog/hellow-world.md
the page works fine and the content gets fetched just fine, but if I tried to localize the content folder by creating separate language folders like this :
content/en/blog/hellow-world.md and changing the fetching method inside blog/index file to include the locale like this :
const i18n = useI18n()


const {data: posts} = await useAsyncData('get-all-posts', () => {
  return queryContent(i18n.locale.value + '/blog').sort({date: -1}).find()
})

then the blog posts are not shown, and I get 404 (Document not found!)
this is the repo link : https://github.com/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/personal-website-nuxt
nuxt.config.ts:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({

    // Devtools
    devtools: {enabled: true},
    modules: [
        '@nuxt/content',
        "@nuxtjs/google-fonts",
        "@nuxtjs/i18n",
        "nuxt-icon",
        "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss"
    ],

    // Nuxt Content options
    content: {
        documentDriven: {},
        highlight: {
            theme: 'github-dark'
        },
        contentHead:true,
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        locales: ['en', 'ar']
    },
    googleFonts: {
        families: {
            'Roboto Mono': [400, 500, 600, 700]
        }
    },


    i18n: {
        vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts',
        strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
        locales: [
            {
                "code": 'en',
                "iso": 'en-US',
                "file": "en-US.ts",
                "dir": "ltr",
                //Custom Properties
                "langName": "English"
            },
            {
                "code": 'ar',
                "iso": 'ar-SY',
                "dir": 'rtl',
                "file": "ar-SY.ts",
                //Custom Properties
                "langName": "العربيّة"

            }
        ],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        lazy: true,
        langDir: 'lang',

    }
})

this is my project tree:
.
├── app.vue
├── assets
│   └── global_scss
│       ├── _breakpoints-mixin.scss
│       ├── global-styles.scss
│       ├── _reset.scss
│       └── _variables.scss
├── components
│   ├── content
│   │   └── MdCustomLink.vue
│   ├── CustomLink
│   │   ├── CustomLink.scss
│   │   └── CustomLink.vue
│   ├── EmploymentCard
│   │   ├── EmploymentCard.scss
│   │   └── EmploymentCard.vue
│   ├── Footer
│   │   ├── Footer.scss
│   │   └── Footer.vue
│   ├── Navbar
│   │   ├── Navbar.scss
│   │   └── Navbar.vue
│   └── Tag
│       ├── Tag.scss
│       └── Tag.vue
├── content
│   ├── ar
│   │   └── blog
│   │       └── hello-world.md
│   └── en
│       └── blog
│           └── hello-world.md
├── i18n.config.ts
├── lang
│   ├── ar-SY.ts
│   └── en-US.ts
├── nuxt.config.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── pages
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── index
│   │   │   ├── index.scss
│   │   │   └── index.vue
│   │   └── [...slug].vue
│   ├── index.scss
│   └── index.vue
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── images
│       ├── blog
│       │   ├── clement-helardot-95YRwf6CNw8-unsplash.jpg
│       │   ├── karl-pawlowicz-QUHuwyNgSA0-unsplash.jpg
│       │   └── nasa-Q1p7bh3SHj8-unsplash.jpg
│       └── my-icon.png
├── README.md
├── server
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── tailwind.config.ts
├── Todo.md
└── tsconfig.json


Apparently, Nuxt content is not compatible with i18n module at the moment. source:
I used this workaround.
